# maven is not compiling test/java classes into target folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I tried cleaning my project through maven->clean and project->clean but it didnot work. I tried changing my output folders explicitly under build path but not sure what to select for src/test/java

I also updated my testng plugin in pom.xml

#### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" >
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <description>Test</description>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
         <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
         <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-ie-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
    
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.37</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
             <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.0</version>
        </dependency>
    
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
    
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
 
  <build>

   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
       <filtering>false</filtering>
       <includes>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
          
        </includes>
     </resource>
   </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>

                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
             
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

Output folders for src/test/java and src/test/resources is /target/classes

and I am getting TestNG class not found in classpath error :

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: testclass file
```

Earlier this code was working fine. I just tried refractoring the project by changing artifact id of maven project and from then not able to proceed.

Comment: Set testng dependency to scope `test` instead of `compile`

Comment: Have you tried running Maven from the command line, or only from Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how widely this applies, but I had success with this:

Right click > Java build path > Source
Make sure Include:(All) and Exclude:(None) is checked for all 4 folders

src/main/java

src/main/resources

src/test/java

src/test/resources

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **maven surefire plugin** to run testNG classes. It's a miracle if you were able to run the tests earlier without this plugin. You have to add below plugin in the build phase to get going.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>Sample.java</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

If you don't want to include the tests manually then by default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:

```
"**/Test*.java"

"**/*Test.java"

"**/*Tests.java"

"**/*TestCase.java"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to convert non-maven project to maven project

```
right click on project->Configure->Convert it to Maven
```

Comment: This is maven project.

Comment: Try this,  Just do Eclipse> Project > Clean and then run the test cases again. It should work. 

What it does in background is, that it will call mvn eclipse:clean in your project directory which will delete your .project and .classpath files and you can also do a mvn eclipse:eclipse - this regenerates your .project and .classpath files. Thus adding the desired class in the classpath.

Comment: tried. not working for me. i am not even seeing my compiled test classes in target folder

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that the "Skip Tests" checkbox was checked.

RClick project -> Run As -> Run Configurations -> Maven Build (select your build configuration) -> Uncheck Skip Tests checkbox

This checkbox prevents Maven from compiling tests

If you want to compile the tests, but don't want to execute them during build process, add -DskipTests in Goals

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try using the following maven command. The following maven command will compile the classes inside src/test folder.

`mvn test-compile`